# Using powershell to manage Active Directory running on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, powershell, active-directory

I would like to create a script that can use the ActiveDirectory module in powershell (from a remote machine).  From what I understand I need to have Active Directory Web Services (ADWS) installed for this to work.  I have two questions:

1. Can I have ADWS on a Server 2003
   machine?
2. If not, can I still use the ActiveDirectory module as long as I run the script on the actual AD machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the AD module on Server 2008 R2. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378783.aspx

You can, however, use the old ADSI libraries from older Windows versions.  Google "ADSI PowerShell" for details.

Answer (score 3):

You CAN install the Active Directory Mgmt Gateway Service on Windows 2003 to manage down-rev AD using the Powershell AD cmdlets.

[According to TechNet:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd391908%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Active Directory Management Gateway Service runs as the Windows Server 2008 R2 ADWS service and provides the same functionality.

You can download and install the Active Directory Management Gateway Service on servers and domain controllers running the following operating systems:

Windows Server® 2003 R2 with Service Pack 2 (SP2)

Windows Server 2003 SP2

Windows Server 2008

Windows Server 2008 SP2

Comment: I would agree with this. My answer should be rejected.